# Newly created branch on github not showing in Xcode "switch to branch" option

Tags: xcode, git, github

I created a branch on github. When i try to switch to this newly created branch from Xcode. Xcode not showing in the "Switch to branch" listing. (Neither in local nor origin)

Comment: You must fetch it first

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Synchronization with remotes in git is not automated and must be performed with an command. `git fetch origin` instructs git to connect to the remote named origin and get a list of refs and associated objects. This would include the new branch on github. At this point you can checkout the branch with `git checkout <branch_name>`.

Comment: running "git fetch origin" within the working directory did the job!

Comment: How to do it without Terminal, in Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527579/xcode-7-doesnt-show-new-remote-branches-using-git

Comment: Is fetch would remove my stashed changes? Or it will be there only I have some very Imp stash changes but also I have to perform fetch to get a new working branch in synch